# Function which obtains assignment code from a variable

Tags: r, function, character, variable-assignment

Let's say that we assign some variable:

```
variable_name <- runif(100) 
letter <- "a" 
listed <- list("a", "b", "C")
```

I would love to have a function `assignment_code(object)` that will output assignment code of these objects i.e.

```
>assignment_code(variable_name)
    "variable_name <- runif(100)"
>assignment_code(letter)
    "letter <- "a""
>assignment_code(listed) 
    "listed <- list("a", "b", "C")"
```

I tried to do it but I wasn't sure how it can be done. I tried to do some magic with `ls()` but I wasn't sure about proper algorithm of picking elements in `ls()`. Do you know how it can be done ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, no it is not possible to find out from an object how it was created, for example the assignments `x <- 1` and `x <- 3-2` would leave `x` looking the same, with no clue as to which was used to create it.

Some possible solutions though are:

- Accessing the history of R to see how variables were created by using the up arrow in Rgui, or the 'history' pane in Rstudio. This is also stored in a file called `.rhistory`.
- Saving all your code as R scripts, so that you have a record of how each variable was created.
- Saving your work as Rmarkdown (integrated well with Rstudio) where the code are resulting output can be combined.